# Is there a way to share common spring boot library between war in an application server?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, weblogic

I have defined a common library using some common classes:

```
<dependencies>
       ...
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     <dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    </dependency>
       ...
</dependency>
```

Now, in my war project I just include the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I then build the war:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>  <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

I would have expected my common lib to be several MBs, but what happens is that, in the war lib folder, I find both my common lib (some Kb) and the 2 declared dependencies in it.

Now, if I wanted to share the dependencies, I would have to deploy all of 3 of them as libs on my application server but what I really want instead is to have just one big common.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The jar should be inside the war. If not, you should add the whole POM so we can see what other configuration might cause this.

Comment: It is but along with other deps that should be inside of it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment of yours. Usually, all dependencies are packed into the war (unless they are `provided` or `test`). If this is not the case with your POM, there must be some configuration that you have not shown to us.

Comment: My intention is to put as "provided" the "my-common" dependency. If I do that I don't find the common lib and that's fine. But I find the spring-boot-starter-test and common-text ones.